# Sharing multiple cookies for the same domain from Microsoft Edge to IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

Edge has the cookie sharing feature that allows sharing of cookies from Edge to IE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare

I have been editing this using edge://compat/SiteListManager and it isn't clear to me how to add multiple cookies for the same domain. The link above to the schema suggests that I should be able to add multiple entries, one for each cookie name that I want to have shared. When I try to add a second one in Edge, it tells me that the "The domain is duplicated" and won't let me add a second cookie name entry.

I tried exporting the one that I had, editing the XML to include the multiple entries, one for each cookie, and then importing, but the import also complains that there are duplicate domain entries and that it will only take the first one.

I also tried in the "Name" field specifying all of the cookie names separated by a newline, but this doesn't seem to work (and doesn't really match what the documented schema says).

This doesn't make any sense to me as most sites have multiple cookies. Why can I only set one shared cookie per domain?

Comment: Based on your description, I reproduced your problem, and I also found that it can't share multiple cookies in the same domain (maybe I missed something), and it pops up like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BFG4.png). I recommend that you can send feedback to relevant team. Just press `Shift+Alt+I` to edit your issue and send it.

Comment: I've sent the feedback, but no reply yet. I have no idea how responsive Microsoft is to such Edge feedback.